# git-lfs not tarcking files even after tracking enabled

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have been struggling with git-lfs since yesterday. I wanted to add a new `.webp` file to a repository and it was too large to push to github. The repo already had another .webp file, but under the github size limit.

I installed gi-lfs, added `*.webp` files to tracking and tried to commit and push.

This did not work. Can't remember the exact sequence of events, but after trying different things (git-lfs migrate) and dealing with a series of unfortunate results - .webp files got altered (the image in them disappeared), repo histories diverged etc., I started fresh today.

- Checked out master (it already had .gitattribute with *.webp tracking enabled)
- Removed the `old.webp` file (the one under size limit). Commit and push.
- Added the `old.webp` file back. Commit and push.
- Created a new branch
- Added the new .webp files (`open.webp` and `closed.webp`, these over size limit)
- Checked `git-lfs ls-files`, it does not list these new .webp files.

```
% git status
On branch new-layout
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   public/images/closed.webp
    new file:   public/images/open.webp

% git-lfs status
On branch new-layout

Objects to be committed:

    public/images/closed.webp (Git: 3190ceb)
    public/images/open.webp (Git: a7d8770)

Objects not staged for commit:

% git commit -m 'new bg images'
[new-layout 4429202] new bg images
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 public/images/closed.webp
 create mode 100644 public/images/open.webp

% git-lfs ls-files
[new-layout 4429202] new bg images
 a8b55ce445 - public/images/old.webp
```

`git-lfs ls-files` only shows the old.webp, and not the new ones I committed.

Also, this is what my `.gitattributes` file looks like:

```
*.webp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to run `git-lfs install`  before adding the new `.webp` files. I am pretty sure I had run `git-lfs install` yesterday on this repo....not sure why I needed to run it again.

So following worked.

1. removed the commit with the new `.webp` files: `git reset --soft HEAD~1`
2. `git-lfs install`
3. add `open.webp` and `close.webp` to the repo
4. `git-lfs ls-files` now lists `open.webp` and `close.webp`. Yay!
5. commit
6. push

Note, running `git-lfs install` after you have already added (but not committed) the new files, does not work. From my experience, you have to run it **before** adding the new files.